# Paint conversion (JAVA NETBEANS)

Tags: java, methods

i'm trying to make a paint conversion project. Eventually I will make a GUI but want to sort of just 
 flesh it out first. I have the code here below. Is there anyone I could maybe simplify this rather than 
 just having a bunch of different methods? Below will the main class and the method class which shows how 
 i calculate everything. Forgive any slopping formatting on here its my first time posting a question.

```
package paintconversion;

/** @author JoshS */
public class Paint2Quart {

  private double Quart;
  private double Gallon;
  private double Pint;

  public Paint2Quart() {
    Quart = 0;
    Gallon = 0;
    Pint = 0;
  }
  // Method to convert Quart to Gallon
  public void setQuartToGallon(double conQuart) {
    if (conQuart > 0) {
      Quart = conQuart / 4;
      System.out.println(conQuart + " quart equals " + Quart + " Gallon(s)");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Numbers Must Be Positive!");
    }
  }
  // Method to convert Gallon To Quart
  public void setGallonToQuart(double conGallon) {
    if (conGallon > 0) {
      Gallon = conGallon * 4;
      System.out.println(conGallon + " gallon equals " + Gallon + " Quart(s)");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Numbers Must Be Positive!");
    }
  }

  public void setPintToGallon(double conPint) {
    if (conPint > 0) {
      Pint = conPint / 8;
      System.out.println(conPint + " pint equals " + Pint + " Gallon(s)");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Numbers Must Be Positive!");
    }
  }

  public void setPintToQuart(double conPint) {
    if (conPint > 0) {
      Pint = conPint / 2;
      System.out.println(conPint + " pint equals " + Pint + " Quart(s)");
    } else {

      System.out.println("Numbers Must Be Positive!");
    }
  }

  public void setGallonToPint(double conGallon) {
    if (conGallon > 0) {
      Gallon = conGallon * 8;
      System.out.println(conGallon + " Gallon equals " + Gallon + " Pint(s)");
    } else {

      System.out.println("Numbers Must Be Positive!");
    }
  }

  public void setQuartToPint(double conQuart) {
    if (conQuart > 0) {
      Pint = conQuart * (2);
      System.out.println(conQuart + " Quart equals " + Pint + " Pint(s)");
    } else {

      System.out.println("Numbers Must Be Positive!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "Forgive any slopping formatting" Most of the formatting issues here would have been in the original code you copied+pasted. Do everybody who you expect to read your code a favour - yourself included - learn to format your code; work out how to get your IDE to format it for you.

Comment: A few general comments: Don't capitalize the names of fields. They begin with a lower case letter by convention in Java. Typically a package name is based on an inverted domain name e.g., com.google.something. If you don't have a domain name to use, I would just leave the package statement out entirely and leave the classes in the default, unnamed package. 'Java' is written mixed case, and the fact that you're using NetBeans is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Is this a class assignment?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks will do, It's my first project that's outside of class so i'm taking off the training wheels so to speak.

Comment: @DavidConrad Duly noted thanks.

Comment: @NomadMaker It isn't I wanted to try it on my own. It's been a few semesters since i took my computer programming 1 and 2 which focused exclusively on java so some of my skills are a bit rusty which is why i wanted to practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert all the quantities to a common unit behind the scenes, and then convert them back as needed. Say, in a class called Volume:

```
public class Volume {
    private double gallons;

    private Volume(double gallons) {
        if (gallons < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must be positive");
        }
        this.gallons = gallons;
    }

    public static Volume ofGallons(double gallons) {
        return new Volume(gallons);
    }

    public static Volume ofQuarts(double quarts) {
        return new Volume(quarts / 4);
    }

    public static Volume ofPints(double pints) {
        return new Volume(pints / 8);
    }

    public static Volume ofLiters(double liters) {
        return new Volume(0.264172 * liters);
    }

    public double asGallons() {
        return gallons;
    }

    public double asQuarts() {
        return gallons * 4;
    }

    public double asPints() {
        return gallons * 8;
    }

    public double asLiters() {
        return gallons / 0.264172;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return gallons + " gallon" + (gallons == 1 ? "" : "s");
    }
}
```

Then, to convert a volume from, say, pints to quarts:

```
quarts = Volume.ofPints(pints).asQuarts();
```

Comment: It seems to me that your `of...()` methods should be static.

Comment: @Abra Whoops! They were supposed to be. Good catch, thanks!

Comment: `ofPints`: Surely there are 8 pints in a gallon, not 8 gallons in a pint.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's what I get for going too fast and not writing unit tests. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. Quick question for the @override part? What does that mean exactly? We touched on it class but that was months ago.

Comment: @JoshSherman The toString method is defined in Object and I'm overriding it here. You can do that without the annotation, but if you use the annotation the compiler will warn you if you didn't really override a method from the superclass or from an interface, and that can be very helpful for avoiding mistakes.

Comment: @DavidConrad OK, thank you. I remember seeing the warning signs that stated that. Thank you for the clarification.